# Get response variables from array

Tags: php, api

I am trying to output all the users I have created in my Marqeta API Sandbox environment. I'm making a GET request to /users through my custom marqetaAPI function that handles each request type.

Call to custom API function:

```
$responseData = MarqetaAPI('GET', 'https://sandbox- 
api.marqeta.com/v3/users/');
```

Custom function API Call with cURL:

```
function marqetaAPI($method, $url, $data, $headers = false) {

//credentials
$uname='xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx';
$pword='xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx';

$curl = curl_init();
switch ($method){
case "POST":
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
if ($data)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
break;
case "PUT":
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
if ($data)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
break;
default:
if ($data)
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
}
// OPTIONS:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
if (!$headers) {
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
// 'APIKEY: $uname:$pword',
'Content-Type: application/json',
));
}else {
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
// 'APIKEY: $uname:$pword',
'Content-Type: application/json',
));
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$uname:$pword");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
// EXECUTE:
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curl);
return $result;
}
```

Decoding response array with json_decode:

```
$responseArray = json_decode($data, true);
```

Here is the json decoded array:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 5
    [start_index] => 0
    [end_index] => 4
    [is_more] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [token] => f7b17921-8f77-4896-82ae-1dc3114ff3e7
                    [active] => 1
                    [uses_parent_account] => 
                    [corporate_card_holder] => 
                    [created_time] => 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
                    [last_modified_time] => 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [account_holder_group_token] => DEFAULT_AHG
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [token] => 638ab57b-bffa-48a7-938f-eae5f3620bd5
                    [active] => 1
                    [uses_parent_account] => 
                    [corporate_card_holder] => 
                    [created_time] => 2020-02-05T15:19:55Z
                    [last_modified_time] => 2020-02-05T15:19:55Z
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [account_holder_group_token] => DEFAULT_AHG
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [token] => 3242d309-1a53-493e-9bfd-dd6351cbb851
                    [active] => 1
                    [uses_parent_account] => 
                    [corporate_card_holder] => 
                    [created_time] => 2020-02-04T16:24:13Z
                    [last_modified_time] => 2020-02-04T16:24:13Z
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [account_holder_group_token] => DEFAULT_AHG
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [token] => 67a045d1-87b7-40fd-8a0f-9c6b88a7f10b
                    [active] => 1
                    [uses_parent_account] => 
                    [corporate_card_holder] => 
                    [created_time] => 2020-02-04T16:23:51Z
                    [last_modified_time] => 2020-02-04T16:23:51Z
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [account_holder_group_token] => DEFAULT_AHG
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [token] => cb12cd70-a119-42a9-ba22-90b88a85f216
                    [active] => 1
                    [uses_parent_account] => 
                    [corporate_card_holder] => 
                    [created_time] => 2020-02-04T16:17:25Z
                    [last_modified_time] => 2020-02-04T16:17:25Z
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [account_holder_group_token] => DEFAULT_AHG
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

        )

)
```

I'm calling the response array nested 'data' key here. The result is 5 arrays (one for each user)

```
foreach($responseArray['data'] as $key=>$value) {
 echo $key . " " . $value . "<br>";
};

//Result
    0 Array
    1 Array
    2 Array
    3 Array
    4 Array
```

Say I wanted the first users keys and values I would do:

```
foreach($response['data'][0] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key . " " . $value . "<br>";
};

//Result
token f7b17921-8f77-4896-82ae-1dc3114ff3e7
active 1
uses_parent_account
corporate_card_holder
created_time 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
last_modified_time 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
metadata Array
account_holder_group_token DEFAULT_AHG
status ACTIVE
```

Now lets say i want to echo each users keys and values I would do something like:

```
//loop over each $response['data'] array
foreach($response['data'] as $userArrays) {

  //loop over each users keys and values
  foreach($userArrays as $key=>$value) {

    echo $key . " " . $value . "<br>";
  };
};
```

with expected output:

```
First User:
token f7b17921-8f77-4896-82ae-1dc3114ff3e7
active 1
uses_parent_account
corporate_card_holder
created_time 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
last_modified_time 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
metadata Array
account_holder_group_token DEFAULT_AHG
status ACTIVE

Second User:
token 67a045d1-87b7-40fd-8a0f-9c6b88a7f10b
active 1
uses_parent_account
corporate_card_holder
created_time 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
last_modified_time 2020-02-05T15:20:49Z
metadata Array
account_holder_group_token DEFAULT_AHG
status ACTIVE

etc.
```

Comment: Can you show us a full structure of your array? Or is the depth variable?

Comment: Without knowing what `$value` contains, it's difficult to say how you need to output it.  You could simply use `print_r($value, true)` in your `echo`.

Comment: _"I think i need a nested foreach but I'm not sure how it is done with keys/values."_ - If `$value` is an array, you can just do another foreach: `foreach ($value as $itemName => $itemValue)`, or what you want to call the variables

Comment: Just show us a `print_r($responseArray)` so we know what we are dealing with. Then show us an example of the result you want

Comment: I just added a link -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc6DI.png

Comment: Say i wanted to only output the tokens for each user in a list

Comment: Look at my answer, i think i have the solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to echo all arrays in `variable depth`, then this function is a solution:

```
function echo_recursive( &$array )  {
  foreach( $array as $key => &$value )  {
    if( is_array( $value ) )  {
      echo_recursive( $value );
    } else {
      echo "$key: $value<br>";
      // or do whatever you want with these
    }
  }
}

// USAGE:
// print_recursive($responseArray);
```

Based on your comment above - `echo only one key`:

```
foreach( $responseArray['data'] as $data )  {
  echo "token: " . $data['token'] . "<br>";
  // echo "active: " . $data['active'] . "<br>";
  // echo "created_time: " . $data['created_time'] . "<br>";
  // and so on...
}
```

Or if you want to `echo all the data`:

```
foreach( $responseArray['data'] as $data )  {
  foreach( $data as $key => $value )  {
    echo "$key: $value<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought i had to assign 'key=>value' to every foreach loop. I guess I got it all wrong

Comment: The recursive function was very useful as well